# how to check auto_ptr is already pointing to an object or not

Tags: compilation, null, g++, compare, auto-ptr

I currently have an auto_ptr:

```
auto_ptr<ClassA> classA_;
```

How can I check whether classA_ points to something or not. If I do:

```
if (classA_ == NULL)
```

to check if its pointing to NULL, it is giving a compile error:
error: no match for 'operator==' in 'classA_ == 0'

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about

```
classA_.get() == 0
```

?